# System installation failed. Substitution of webkitgtk-2.20.5. GuixSD Linux

Tags: system-installation, guixsd

When I install GuixSD on my computer, not VM, it fails at downloading the package webkitgtk-2.20.5 each time. The progress of its downloading is from 71 to 78%. There is an info that a device is full:

```
guix system: error: build failed: writing to file: No space left on device
```

But a `df -h` comamnd shows that even 16G is available on /mnt mounting. How to fix it and finish the installation? Here you are a terminal info:

```
(...)
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/mmnv4y0n0mmddhfpjjr9mzfy5994542z-gnome-disk-utility-3.28.3...
 gnome-disk-utility-3.28.3  2.0MiB                                                                                     52KiB/s 00:39 [##################] 100.0%
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/f9rjpq9m5cmp7abkqb3y7xrg4r0ip02c-gst-plugins-good-1.14.3...
 gst-plugins-good-1.14.3  2.9MiB                                                                                       44KiB/s 01:07 [##################] 100.0%
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/shs1ps27f75mrx3chird1riwfl1k09hj-gvfs-1.32.1...
 gvfs-1.32.1  2.1MiB                                                                                                   54KiB/s 00:40 [##################] 100.0%
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/pwxpnpqg3cjbx5v88idfg49x7236b56h-totem-3.26.2...
 totem-3.26.2  3.0MiB                                                                                                  52KiB/s 01:00 [##################] 100.0%
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/jxpax5lv5affxqxidlwa7b7wk8jvsccb-nautilus-3.26.2...
 nautilus-3.26.2  5.1MiB                                                                                               48KiB/s 01:49 [##################] 100.0%
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/fd706jbvrk8zvk6175sz42xqbgc3krsg-webkitgtk-2.20.5...
guix substitute: error: fport_write: No space left on device                                                           50KiB/s 10:20 [############      ]  71.5% webkitgtk-2.20.5  42.3MiB                                                                                             50KiB/s 10:21 [############      ]  71.5%gzip: stdout: Broken pipe
substitution of /gnu/store/fd706jbvrk8zvk6175sz42xqbgc3krsg-webkitgtk-2.20.5 failed                                    70KiB/s 10:21 [##################] 100.0%killing process 12511
guix system: error: build failed: writing to file: No space left on device
root@gnu ~# guix system init /mnt/etc/config.scm /mnt --skip-checks --fallback
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/6g29969ca9klj136ml68qg96kdvd4if1-xdg-user-dirs-0.17...
 xdg-user-dirs-0.17  47KiB                                                                                            705KiB/s 00:00 [##################] 100.0%
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/fd706jbvrk8zvk6175sz42xqbgc3krsg-webkitgtk-2.20.5...
guix substitute: error: fport_write: No space left on device                                                           52KiB/s 10:35 [#############     ]  76.9% webkitgtk-2.20.5  42.3MiB                                                                                             52KiB/s 10:36 [#############     ]  76.9%gzip: stdout: Broken pipe
substitution of /gnu/store/fd706jbvrk8zvk6175sz42xqbgc3krsg-webkitgtk-2.20.5 failed                                    68KiB/s 10:36 [##################] 100.0%killing process 12556
guix system: error: build failed: writing to file: No space left on device
root@gnu ~# guix system init /mnt/etc/config.scm /mnt --skip-checks --fallback
downloading from https://ci.guix.info/nar/gzip/fd706jbvrk8zvk6175sz42xqbgc3krsg-webkitgtk-2.20.5...
guix substitute: error: fport_write: No space left on device                                                           47KiB/s 11:46 [#############     ]  76.9% webkitgtk-2.20.5  42.3MiB                                                                                             47KiB/s 11:47 [#############     ]  77.0%gzip: stdout: Broken pipe
substitution of /gnu/store/fd706jbvrk8zvk6175sz42xqbgc3krsg-webkitgtk-2.20.5 failed                                    61KiB/s 11:47 [##################] 100.0%killing process 12594
guix system: error: build failed: writing to file: No space left on device
root@gnu ~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
none            2.0G  2.0G  312K 100% /
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc1        18G  986M   16G   6% /mnt
root@gnu ~#
```

Answer (score 0):

> guix system: error: build failed: writing to file: No space left on device

You should enable `cow` before initializing the system:

```
herd start cow-store /mnt
```

[6.1.5 Proceeding with the Installation](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/en/html_node/Proceeding-with-the-Installation.html#Proceeding-with-the-Installation)

> ```
> herd start cow-store /mnt
> ```
>
> This makes `/gnu/store` copy-on-write, such that packages added to it during the installation phase are written to the target disk on /mnt rather than kept in memory. This is necessary because the first phase of the guix system init command (see below) entails downloads or builds to /gnu/store which, initially, is an in-memory file system.

the `webkitgtk` is a dependency for the `gnome-desktop` defaut browser. The derivative build may take a long time because you have enabled the local buid through `--fallback` option.

> [--fallback](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/en/html_node/Common-Build-Options.html)
>
> When substituting a pre-built binary fails, fall back to building packages locally (see Substitution Failure).

The [default configuration](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/en/html_node/Using-the-Configuration-System.html#Using-the-Configuration-System) include both Xfce and Gnome ,

```
  (services (cons* (gnome-desktop-service)
               (xfce-desktop-service)
               %desktop-services))
```

You can install only one desktop by editing the `config.scm` file. e,g: to install only the Xfce4 desktop:

```
  (services (cons* (xfce-desktop-service)
               %desktop-services))
```